# Line break in source code renders to a no-width whitespace when aligned right and using <br>

Tags: html, safari

The following bug seems to only appear in Safari. When paragraphs are `right`-aligned and contain a `<br>` tag line breaks are not rendered properly. For example:

```html
<p style="text-align:right">
  This is a test
  with two lines.
  <br/>
</p>
```

Renders as:

> This is a testwith two lines.

Instead of

> This is a test with two lines.

I can't manage to reproduce this consistently, but the above code sometimes produces the bug. If I alt-tab away and back or if I open/close developer console the bug will usually show-up. Note that `<br/>` is important here, the bug doesn't appear if it's not present.

One important detail, if I copy-paste the rendered text, the space is present in the clipboard. Also, in case that helps, the file is encoded as `text/html; charset=utf-8` it's hosted on an OVH web server. The bug never shows on codepen.

I've hosted this minimal working example here: [safari-bug.html](https://kune.travel/test/safari-bug.html). I'll try to keep this alive as long as possible.

Comment: What are you expecting to come from this question? Apple has a [support site for Safari](https://support.apple.com/safari) and a [contact form for submitting bugs](https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html). Stack Overflow is a site for problems with programming that can be remedied by fellow developers; the best we could do is maybe get you a workaround for the issue.

Comment: I don't know much about HTML rendering, maybe I've done something wrong here. I don't know, so I can't tell what I expect. That's why I ask this question, maybe it's not really a "bug" per se.